# Identify a file that contains a particular string in PHP/SQL site

Tags: php, content-management-system, phpmyadmin

By using the inspect element feature of Chrome I have identified a string of text that needs to be altered to lower case.

Though the string appears on all the pages in the site, I am not sure which file to edit.

The website is a CMS based on PHP and SQL - I am not so familiar with these programs.

I have searched through the files manually and cannot find the string.

Is there a way to search and identify the file I need using, for example, the inspect element feature on browsers or in FTP tool such as Filezilla?

Comment: If it's a CMS, are you sure that the text isn't stored in the database?

Comment: Which CMS are you using and what part of the page is it? We need to know if this is part of the template (a file) or content (in the database), and if it's in the database, which CMS you're using will help the search greatly.

Comment: the site is here: http://tinyurl.com/c8djrvr, the CMS is a less well known one called "Ushahidi". The text may be stored in the database I am not sure - this is out of my knowledge range. The string in question is within the google analytics tag, where I'd like to put to lower case the instance of the word "TRUE" as a per a previous SO question I had. The tag appears at the bottom of the page, immediatley after the footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have a layout page of any kind in your CMS. If you do, then most probably either in that file, or in the footer include file you will find either the javascript for google analytics, or a js include file for the same.

Try doing a site search for `'UA-34035531-1'` (which is your google analytics user key) and see if it returns anything. If you find it, what you need would be two lines under it.

Usually people do not put analytics code in DB, so there is a bigger chance you will find it in one of the files, which most probably is included/embedded in a layout file of some sort, as you need it across all pages in the site

Comment: Wait, on your second sentence on doing a site search, do you mean within inspect element program? I did that and found the instance but "two lines under" says "function"? Could you clarify?